# Webforms missing asterisk for required form components

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a [form](http://landberg.at/en/newsletter-subscription) using the [Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). But where are my (red) asteriks for the required form components? How do i enable those? My fields are set to `required`.

Comment: here is a patch https://www.drupal.org/node/1025706 you can take a look.

Comment: thanks. How do i exactly applying a patch? I am using latest version (7.x-4.12). Can i safely use this patch?

Comment: @Smalution That patch landed in early 2011, probably not helpful!

Comment: This sounds like it could be a theme problem: are you using a custom theme?

Comment: @Andy thanks. I am using Bootstrap and then my bootstrap subtheme...

Comment: I'd suggest: try switching back to a core theme to confirm it's a theme problem. If it works with a core theme, check it works with plain Bootstrap. If it works then you know it's an issue with your subtheme. For normal form elements I believe [`theme_form_element_label()`][1] is the theme implementation used, I can't remember if webform uses it normally or not. You can verify the actual theme implementation used with [devel_themer][2].

[1]: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element_label/7
[2]: https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer